# Can we have a series representation of order $5$ at $x=0$ of the inverse function of $xe^{x^{2}}$?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, inverse, inverse-function

Well, I am a freshman, This was my homework. 
With a bit of googling, I found that:
$$f^{-1}(x) = \pm \frac{\sqrt{W(2x^2)}}{\sqrt{2}}$$
What our professor did was:
$$  f(x)=xe^{x^{2}}=x+x^3+\dfrac{x^5}{2} +O(x^6)  $$
Then he proved that $f(x)$ is a bijection then he supposed that:
$$f^{-1}(x) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+a_5x^5+O(x^6)$$
then
$$
f^{-1}(f(x))=x
$$
$$
f^{-1}(f(x))=a_0+a_1{(x+x^3+\dfrac{x^5}{2})}+a_2{(x+x^3+\dfrac{x^5}{2})}^2+a_3{(x+x^3+\dfrac{x^5}{2})}^3+a_4{(x+x^3+\dfrac{x^5}{2})}^4+a_5{(x+x^3+\dfrac{x^5}{2})}^5
$$

then solved the following for the coefficient:
$$
a_0+a_1{(x+x^3+\dfrac{x^5}{2})}+a_2{(x+x^3+\dfrac{x^5}{2})}^2+a_3{(x+x^3+\dfrac{x^5}{2})}^3+a_4{(x+x^3+\dfrac{x^5}{2})}^4+a_5{(x+x^3+\dfrac{x^5}{2})}^5=x
$$
and found that:
$$
a_0=0,a_1=1,a_2=0,a_3=-1,a_5=\dfrac{5}{2}
$$
and found that:
$$f^{-1}(x)=x-x^3+\dfrac{5x^5}{2} +O(x^6)$$
I Think it is wrong because when you plot both of them, they are not symmetric to $y = x$

Comment: shouldn't it be $f^{-1}(x)=x-x^3-\frac{x^5}{2}+O(x^6)$?

Comment: yes it is, but even though still not symmetrical

Comment: and why is that important?

Comment: @PinkPanther because function and its inverse are symmetric to y=x

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text{I don't agree with} \quad f^{-1}(x)=x-x^3-\dfrac{1}{2}x^5 +O(x^6)$$
I found :
$$f^{-1}(x)=x-x^3+\dfrac{5}{2}x^5 +O(x^6)$$

But my answer is mainly about the question of symmetry to $y=x$.

Sure, you are right. The curves $y(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ must be symmetrical.

The series $y=x-x^3+\dfrac{5}{2}x^5$ is an approximate of $f^{-1}(x)$ only accurate in a range close to the origin. So, don't expect to observe symmetrical curves if you consider a too large range from the origin.

This is illustrated on the figure below.

$y=x$ is drawn in black.

$x\,e^{x^2}$ is drawn in red (solid curve).

$f^{-1}(x) $ is drawn in red (dashed curve), that is the symmetric curve of $x\,e^{x^2}$.

$x-x^3+\dfrac{5}{2}x^5$ is the first blue curve. One can see that the approximation is correct only on a small range, approximately $x<0.3$

More accuracy requires more terms for the series. For example :
$x-x^3+\dfrac{5}{2}x^5-\dfrac{49}{6}x^7+\dfrac{243}{8}x^9-\dfrac{14641}{120}x^{11}$ is the second blue curve.

One can see that the range is not much enlarged, approximately $x<0.4$ . This is only a small improvement. Definitively one cannot expect a large range of validity for the inverse function with this method of limited series expansion, even with a large number of terms.

[image]